# Python Pandas - check if value exists in 1 dataframe and update value in another dataframe based on results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes.

`Orders` and `Receipts`.

Both `Orders` and `Receipts` have a column named `Request Number`.

Orders have an additional Column named `Received`.

I need to compare `['Request Number']` columns and determine whether there's a matching field (eg 123456) inside either dataframes.

If it exists in either dataframes `Received` value in `Orders` should change to `True` else stay `False`.

I tried the following with no luck - it output `False`, despite knowing there's matching fields.

```
orders['Received'] = orders['Request Number'].apply(lambda x: True if x in receipts['Request Number'] else False)
```

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check membership:

```
orders['Received'] = orders['Request Number'].isin(receipts['Request Number'])
```

> Any suggestions why it's not working?

You can check [using the in operator](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#using-the-in-operator):

> Using the Python **in** operator on a Series tests for membership in the index, not membership among the values.

So possible solution is convert values to numpy array:

```
orders['Received'] = (orders['Request Number']
                        .apply(lambda x: x in receipts['Request Number'].to_numpy()))
```